# PDF Generation Tool for .NET (comparisons and experience)

Tags: .net, pdf

I'm looking for people's experience with pdf generation tools to use with .net (C#/asp.net). I've done many web searches and I see tons of stuff out there, but I'm looking for someone who has experience with them and could give out a few pointers why I would go with or not go with some.

I've taken a look at the open source one, iTextSharp and have not had an easy time with it. And to be honest, my employer would rather spend hundreds or thousands on a pdf library than to pay for the "iText in Action" book.

At this point, I simply need to pass the library some html and have it generate a pdf file from it. I have the code working doing this with iTextSharp, but having a rough time getting the css style to be recognized.

Comment: "...At this point, I simply need to pass the library some html and have it generate a pdf file from it." Have you checked this? http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Comment: iTextSharp is a very good low level pdf library. It's api is very similar to the actual pdf spec, making it great to modify pdfs because you can change precisely what you want but a lot of work to generate pdfs.

Comment: Do you wish to use a module or a write it from scratch? I have no idea if this is what your looking for but http://www.html-to-pdf.net/ offers C# and VB.NET Samples

Comment: I've worked with [Winnovative](http://www.winnovative-software.com) library at my job and it was pretty easy to use. It supports external css files.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the Report Builder that comes with Visual Studio.  You can visually design the output and export directly to a PDF file (you can bypass the Report Viewer).

Otherwise, as @jbutle suggested, iTextSharp is very popular.